# Exercise 2.2 from the book "The concept and practice of Mathematical Finance"

Tags: option-pricing

I am a newbie. Please help me understand how to resolve the exercise 2.2 from the book "[The concept and practice of Mathematical Finance](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Concepts_and_Practice_of_Mathematica.html?id=hAT9wO3bzt0C)". The solution from the book says that our super-replicating portfolio will be $\alpha$ shares and $\beta$ bonds. It must dominate at zero. This implies that $\beta$ >= 0. 
First of all, what does it mean "it must dominate at zero". Secondly, why if it dominates at zero, then $\beta$ >= 0? Thanks so much for your help!

### Problem

[image]

### Solution

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Jack, could you please post the question as well? Not every user has easy access to the book.

Comment: Here is the question, Each of the following products pays a function of spot price, S, of a non-dividen-paying stock one year from now. If there is no interest rates and spot is 100, give the optimal upper and lower bounds on their prices today. (i) The pay-off is 1 between 110 and 130 and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

"It must dominate at zero" means that when the final spot level is zero, the value of the super-replicating portfolio must be greater than or equal to the value of the payoff, which is zero.  Since the super-replicating portfolio consists of some stock (which has zero value when the spot price is zero) and some bonds (which have value one), there must be a non-negative number of bonds.

Answer (score 1):

"Dominating at zero" is what it sounds like:  It means that the value of the portfolio has a >0 value when the spot price (and α) is at 0.

So if α = 0 then β must be a positive (non zero) value in order to "dominate" or be >= 0.